# How to add to PATH in raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I'm using composer to install development tools in raspbian. How do I add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to the PATH so I can accessed installed packages from composer in raspbian?

I tried adding to `~/.profile/` but when I reboot it no longer works.

Any ideas?

Comment: are we supposed to guess what you have?

Comment: I'm not sure `~` works in the .profile file. Better try the full path, so `/home/pi/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: @Gerben or `$HOME`

Answer (score 3):

The following adds a line to /etc/profile to export PATH after startup.
( /my/subFolder is added to the current PATHS )

```
sudo sed -i 's/export PATH/PATH=$PATH:\/my\/subFolder\nexport PATH/g' /etc/profile
```

Keep in mind that Raspbian is Debian based. You may want to have a look at how it is done in Debian (and similarly can be done in Raspbian). Something you may need to look at also is runLevel you're running (i.e. singleUser, multiUser or GUI) - but the above may be enough.

https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables